# Redirect *.example.com to example.com

Tags: domains, redirects, subdomain, linux, httpd.conf

I have some valid subdomains in my httpd.conf file. Now how do I redirect anything that's not a valid subdomain to the main website? What I mean is, if I have a valid subdomain hello.example.com, it should go to hello.example.com and if its blah.example.com which is not a valid subdomain, it should go to example.com. How can I make changes in my httpd.conf file to follow everything I just mentioned?

Comment: which server is that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It's Linux CentOS 64 bit using Apache(httpd) process.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a new default site in your apache-config and rewrite the url via .htaccess if this default site is called. Maybe something like /var/www/invalid-subdomain/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [R,L]
```

The above example is working well for my apache2 squeeze server.

Comment: Well.. Thanks for the reply. But I need to use this in the config file itself. There might be a rewrite rule to point wrong hosts(blah.example.com) to the root host(example.com) but I don't have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache and if you have virtual hosts enabled, you got it automagically:

- First virtualhost will be default host, which will serve all requests for hosts, not defined as virtual hosts
- Known in Apache virtual hosts will be used on request

PS: hello.example.com and blah.example.com **are hosts, not subdomains**

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the help. I'm a newbie in this area, please forgive the mistake. I'm not sure about what you mentioned.